# woocommerce breadcrumbs - show categories only, retain last crumb anchor

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

essentially, i'm trying to remove the first and last crumbs, while retaining the anchor link on the last crumb left. currently, i am able to remove the first (home) and last crumbs (product title), but this leaves the last crumb without an anchor.

current code:

```
// Remove Home breadcrumb
add_filter('woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', function( $defaults ) {
    unset($defaults['home']); //removes home link.
    return $defaults; //returns rest of links
});

// Remove  last breadcrumb
function fls_remove_last_breadcrumb( $crumbs ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && is_woocommerce() ) {
        array_pop( $crumbs );
    }
    return $crumbs;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', 'fls_remove_last_breadcrumb', 40 );
```

[image]

Comment: _"but this leaves the last crumb without an anchor"_ - the last one is always without a link, because that is supposed to be the page you are currently on. By removing the product title entry, you made the "Outdoor Seating" the new last one. You will either have to modify the logic where these get output as HTML; or maybe go for a CSS solution instead (if the structure allows for that, can't tell how exactly those separating `/` are inserted.)